# Plot and export ERA5 wind data for the whole world: GRIB format

Tags: wind, python

I have ERA5 wind data information in GRIB format for the whole earth for September 2017 (all days and hours). This gives me around 912 variables in the list.

[image]

I am trying to plot it using the code I found online in jupyterlab. However, it does not show me any plot.
Also, when I run these codes, the jupyter lab kernel restarts.

```
ax1 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))

ax1.coastlines()

ax1.stock_img()
```

Apart from that, I am also trying to extract information the information only for island of Dominica or boundary box extent [N:15.88, W:-62.21, S:14.78, E:-60.68]
Please tell me how can I modify this code so I can plot the information fo my aoi and also extract the information.

```
import pygrib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
import sys

file = 'Whole_earth.grib'
grbs = pygrib.open(file)
for g in grbs:
    lats, lons = g.latlons() # lats - latitude, lons - longitude
    lats, lons = np.array(lats), np.array(lons)

grb_uwind = grbs.select()[0] #U 10m wind component for 2017-09-08 
grb_vwind = grbs.select()[1] #V 10m wind component for 2017-09-08
data_uwind = grb_uwind.values #U 10m wind values in m/s
data_vwind = grb_vwind.values #V 10m wind values in m/s

print(lons.shape)
print(lats.shape)
print(data_uwind.shape)
print(data_vwind.shape)

ax1 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))

ax1.coastlines()

ax1.stock_img()

ax1.set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 359.99], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.set_yticks([-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True,
                               number_format='.0f')
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
ax1.barbs(lons[::50,::50],lats[::50,::50],data_uwind[::50,::50],
  data_vwind[::50,::50],transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.savefig('esse.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I recommend you use [Xarray](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/getting-started-guide/quick-overview.html) for reading grib/netcdf files. Subsetting is quite easy in Xarray, among other functions/methods to process weather/climate.

Comment: I have also used xarray...
But still I am unable to plot the u an v winds and also cannot plot them. @RogUE

Comment: Could you try running the program directly, without using JupyterLab? Maybe in Spyder IDE? It could be something with the JupyterLab.